# What is the most elegant, reliable and efficient way to get the grandparent's first child in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, algorithm, jquery-events

I have a piece of HTML like

```
<form action="/AssetBundle/DownloadFile" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#masterLinkHolder" id="form0" method="post"></form>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>someimage.png</td>
          <td><img src="imageicon.png"></td>
          <td><button type="button">Click to Download</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>somedocument.docx</td>
          <td><img src="docicon.png"></td>
          <td><button type="button">Click to Download</button></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" id="file2Download" />
</form>
```

and when a `button` is clicked I want to set the `value` of the input with `id` `file2Download` to be the file name (e.g. `someimage.png`, `somedocument.docx`) from the same `tr` as the button, and then submit the form. So I need help filling out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('#file2Download').val(
           // ... ?
        );
        $('#id0').submit();
    });
</script>
```

in the proper way. I know that I'm looking at a tree like

```
               tr
           /   |    \ 
          td   td    td
               |      \
              img     button
```

and trying to go from the `button` to the grandparent `tr` and then to the first child of that `tr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#file2Download').val( 
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text()
);
```

`.closest()` will take you up the DOM from the button to the closest table row (`<tr>`), then `.find('td:first').text()` will search down the DOM and take the first table cell's text contents.

BTW, I assume you didn't mean `$('#id0')` in your example since your form's ID is `form0`, which would be selected via `$('#form0')`.

Comment: Would it be better `closest()` or `parentsUntil()`? or would it be the same?

Comment: I understand they are not the same, but would it be more efficient to use one over the other? Is one of them faster? Is `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text()` faster than `(this).parentsUntil('table').find('td:first').text()`?

Comment: Why doesn't my question make any sense? Don't the two pieces of code I shared return the same result? What is wrong about asking which one would be faster taking into account that OP asked about efficiency?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - parentsUntil() is really meant more for gathering ancestors of an element up to, and not including, a certain element. Parents() would be closer than parentsUntil() to closer(). And in this case, the performance of parents() and closest() are nearly identical.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was just curious about it (and I should have gone with `parents()` instead of `parentsUntil()`)

Comment: @humblerumble thanks for the comparison data. Btw, great answer

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

The accepted answer is the second slowest suggestion.

The difference between vanilla javascript and jQuery is huge.

There are many ways to skin a cat, or find a grandparents first child.

Use vanilla javascript whenever possible.

## Results

Here are the [jsPerf results](http://jsperf.com/select-first-td-of-grandparent) of all of the methods suggested thus far. Remember that higher numbers for ops/sec are better, I've ordered them from quickest to slowest

1. `Element.parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild.textContent;`

   @canon
   ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/2/))
   characters = 60
   ops/sec    = 3,239,703
2. `Element.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].textContent;`

   @canon
   ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/3/))
   characters = 54
   ops/sec    = 1,647,235
3. `Element.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].textContent;`

   @canon
   ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/4/))
   characters = 51
   ops/sec    = 1,558,070
4. `Element.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('td:first-child').textContent;`

   @Tiny Giant
   ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/5/))
   characters = 74
   ops/sec    = 1,189,826
5. `document.getElementById(Element.dataset.select).textContent;`

   @guest271314
   ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/6/))
   characters = 60
   ops/sec    = 800,876
6. `$('#' + $(Element).data('select')).text();`

   @guest271314
   ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/7/))
   characters = 42
   ops/sec    = 47,144
7. `$('td:first-child',Element.parentNode.parentNode).text();`

   @Tiny Giant
   ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/8/))
   characters = 57
   ops/sec    = 18,305
8. `$(Element).parent().siblings(":eq(0)").text();`

   @guest271314
   ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/9/))
   characters = 46
   ops/sec    = 17,633
9. `$(Element).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();`

   @j08691
   ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/10/))
   characters = 49
   ops/sec    = 4,511
10. `$(Element).parentsUntil('table').find('td:first').text();`

    @AlvaroMontoro
    ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xxuL0bh/11/))
    characters = 54
    ops/sec    = 3,954

The first five methods all use vanilla javascript where the last five use jQuery. There is a very significant drop in ops/sec in even the fastest jQuery solution. The difference between the slowest vanilla method vs the fastest jQuery method puts the jQuery method at 1/17th the speed of the vanilla method.

As you can see the accepted answer is the second slowest. I would caution against the use of closest in this situation. The more specific you can be the faster it will run, and closest just turns it into a guessing game.

This just goes to show, while it may take a little bit more time to type, it **will always be faster** to use vanilla javascript. What's even better, vanilla javascript is included by default!

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant and efficient way to get the requisite *grandparent's first child* is to use plain old javascript. In this particular case, you already know exactly where to get the value you want. Just go get it by explicitly navigating the DOM on your own:

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {

  var el = this         // button
    .parentNode         // parent
    .parentNode         // grandparent
    .firstElementChild; // grandparent's first child
  
  console.log(el.textContent);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>someimage.png</td>
    <td><button type="button">Click to Download</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>somedocument.docx</td>
    <td><button type="button">Click to Download</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That's about as fast as you'll ever get. Comparable jQuery code is actually [much, much slower](http://jsperf.com/grandparent-first-child), i.e.: ≤ 4.2% of the speed. All you'd *maybe* gain from a jQuery solution is a few characters. The moral of the story is, **don't be afraid to use vanilla javascript in your jQuery environment**. Use either or both where it makes sense.

Now, for cases in which you're unsure of your target element's position in the reference element's ancestry, check out [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
var text = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first-child").text();
```

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  var text = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first-child").text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>someimage.png</td>
    <td><button type="button">Click to Download</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>somedocument.docx</td>
    <td><button type="button">Click to Download</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#file2Download').val(
  $(this).parent().siblings(":eq(0)").text()
);
```

```js
$('button').click(function () {
        $('#file2Download').val(
           $(this).parent().siblings(":eq(0)").text()
        );        
      console.log($("#file2Download").val())
      //$('#id0').submit();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#masterLinkHolder" id="form0" method="post"></form>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>someimage.png</td>
          <td><img src="imageicon.png"></td>
          <td><button type="button">Click to Download</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>somedocument.docx</td>
          <td><img src="docicon.png"></td>
          <td><button type="button">Click to Download</button></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" id="file2Download" />
</form>
```

---

Note, See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30336313/

An alternative would be to add a `data-*` attribute to `button` elements , an `id` to first `td` ; could then select first `td` directly based on clicked button `data-id="first-td"`

html

```
<form action="/AssetBundle/DownloadFile" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#masterLinkHolder" id="form0" method="post"></form>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td id="select1">someimage.png</td>
          <td><img src="imageicon.png"></td>
          <td><button type="button" data-select="select1">Click to Download</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td id="select2">somedocument.docx</td>
          <td><img src="docicon.png"></td>
          <td><button type="button" data-select="select2">Click to Download</button></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" id="file2Download" />
</form>
```

js

```
$("#file2Download").val(document.getElementById(this.dataset.select).textContent)
```

Comment: Why would you want to get the entire set of siblings before filtering? This certainly doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: @canon Ok, Nearly all of the solutions appear to contain some form of collection returned , then some form of filtering; whether utilizing `find()`, `cells`; though humble.rumble 's solution at `$('td:first-child', Element.parentNode.parentNode);` seems to get right to point. Adjusted original post minimally , to provide `:eq(0)` as expression to `.siblings()` _"The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type that we can pass to the $() function. If the selector is supplied, the elements will be filtered by testing whether they match it."_ http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: @canon Updated post should actually only call on two elements: `$(this).parent()` and `td` at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let's shed light on the matter that can arise when thinking of the most reliable & efficient way. I will briefly write here about the closest() and parent() functions, so as to make it clear to any reader which to use, when and why.

closest() gets the first element that matches the selector, a jQuery object which we pass onto the function, by testing the given jQuery object and traversing up the DOM tree looking for its ancestors.

parent() travels a single element up the DOM tree and selects the immediate element who is parent to the given jQuery object.

Their difference is significant, despite the fact that they both seem to function similarly as how they traverse up the DOM tree.

Differences:

closest() - Begins with the current element. Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector. The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each element in the original set, in document order

parent() - Begins with the parent element. Travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied. The returned jQuery object contains zero or more elements for each element in the original set, in reverse document order.

Therefore, parent would computationally provide a faster search due to its nature of going up a level into the parent tree structure. Keep in mind that this is the case since we're looking to find the grandparent.

Please refer to the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) for more details on implementation.